# How to reduce the separation from other text using LaTeX minted?

Tags: latex, spacing, pygments

I want to use the minted package to give me syntax highlighting but it has a spacing of more than a centimeter.

Setting:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
```

does not help at all. Is there any way to reduce the spacing from the rest of the text?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

minted internally uses the `Verbatim` environment from the fancyvrb package. In the documentation of the implementation, the following formula for the spaces is given:

> ```
> <topskip> = \topsep + \partopsep + \parskip 
> <botskip> = \topsep + \partopsep
> ```

And

> Except when in label or after nobreak, `\parskip` is added with `\addvspace`, so that net space is:
>
> ```
> MAX{\topsep (+\partopsep) + \parskip , \lastskip }
> ```
>
> (The usual `\@item` works the same way.)

Hence, setting `\partopsep` to some other value does the trick; I’ve tried it, and you need a *negative* value to remove the margin:

```
\setlength\partopsep{-\topsep}
```

This removes most of the space between the text body and the code. To get a distance of 0.5cm, add its distance to that:

```
\setlength\partopsep{-\topsep}
\addtolength\partopsep{-\parskip}
\addtolength\partopsep{0.5cm}
```

An implementation can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19423

Comment: I like how this answer appears to be so much simpler than the one liked to. :)

Comment: This affects more than `minted` environments.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Yes, of course: the first sentence in my answer should have made that clear. If you want it to only affect minted environments, use `\newenvironment` in conjunction with `\VerbatimEnvironment` to redefine the variables locally, or use the solution I’ve linked at the very end of my answer to adjust all fancyvrb `Verbatim` environments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the line spacing you can use:

```
\linespread{1.0}
```

And play a little bit around with the number in the curly brackets.

The commands you have given as an example refer to the page environment.
See [this Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) for additional explanations and examples.

Comment: That helps a bit.

The problem is that I have the following code:

An example piece of HTML code would look like:
\begin{minted}[frame=lines, framesep=2mm]{html}
<b>Hello</b>
\end{minted}
The output of this example in a browser would be: {\bf Hello} .

When I but this in my document there is a gap of a centimeter before and after the minted environment. I want to reduce this distance to half a centimeter. How to do that?

Comment: @cvandonderen take a look at Konrad's answer, that should do the trick.